If a known ellipse and partially known circle are tangent to each other, how can we find the equation of the partially known circle?
The known ellipse has the equation $4(x+0.5)^2 + 2y^2 = 1$.  The unknown circle has a center of $(-1,k)$ and we know that it contains the point $(-1,1)$.
I was able to determine that the formula for the circle is $(x+1)^2 + (y-k)^2 = (1-k)^2$.
However, I'm not sure what to do to find the value of k.
(I did a similar problem with two circles that are externally tangent.  In that problem, I was able to find the equation because I knew that the distance between the two centers is equal to the sum of the radii of each circle.  Not sure what to do with a circle and an ellipse externally tangent....)
Here's an image of what the situation looks like.  What is the equation of that circle if the two conic sections were tangent to each other as shown?


For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

There is not a unique such circle; there are two.

What tools are to be used here? Calculus? Trig? Vectors? Have you learned any theorems about conics that could be relevant? ... Such information can help readers target their responses to best serve you, without explaining things you already understand or using techniques with which you aren't yet familiar. ... Good luck!

Thanks for editing!  I’m not sure what you mean about there being two circles.

The problem is to be done with knowledge of conics, no calculus preferably.  I feel like I need to use the foci of the ellipse but that’s just a guess.

@AlexHyun: Please put such clarifications into the body of the question. Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden. ... (BTW: The "two circles" mentioned by Numeral likely refer to the internally and externally tangent solutions. (The former is easy.) The problem as stated doesn't seem to distinguish, although your parenthetical does.)
